# an element of a tensor product of modules not equal to any generator.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am trying to find a right $R$-module $A$ and a left $R$-module $B$ such that the tensor product $A\otimes_R B$ has an element that is not of the form $a\otimes b$ for any $a,b$ in $A,B$ respectively. I could not find any. Is there any simple example? Thanks in advance

Edit: You may bring other examples, or consider my own example that taking $A,B$ to be $K^2$ for a field $K$, then $e_1\otimes e_1 + e_2\otimes e_2$ where $e_i$ are the canonical basis elements of $K$ is such an element but how can it be proved using elementary methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example will do.  Note in particular that every generator can be expanded as 
$$
(a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2) \otimes (b_1 e_1 +b_2 e_2) = \\
a_1b_1\,e_1 \otimes e_1 + a_1 b_2 \,e_1\otimes e_2+ a_2b_1\,e_2 \otimes e_1 + a_2 b_2\,e_2 \otimes e_2
$$
From there, it suffices to prove that the system of equations
$$
a_1b_1 = 1\\
a_1b_2 = 0\\
a_2 b_1 = 0\\
a_2b_2 = 1
$$
has no solutions (in any field).  In particular, it suffices to observe because of the second equation, $a_1 = 0$ or $b_2 = 0$. Consequently, either the first or last equation must fail to be true.

An interesting observation is that the tensor
$$
a_{11}\,e_1 \otimes e_1 + a_{12} \,e_1\otimes e_2+ a_{21}\,e_2 \otimes e_1 + a_{22}\,e_2 \otimes e_2
$$
can be written as a generator if and only if the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}}
$$
has rank $1$.  In fact, this condition holds true for elements of $K^m \otimes K^n$ for arbitrary $m,n$.

Comment: Thanks, this solution was also instrucive to me since I’m new to abstract algebra